# spark, insert 30 days data from a uniq kafka request

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

I have 1 event from kafka with this content :

```
(date,
user_id,
app_id,
duration,
session_id,
....)
```

I use this code to get the topic  :

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
        ssc, kafkaParams, Map(topicSessionDuration -> 2), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)
        .map(_._2)
        .map(RawSessionData(_))
```

And i store in cassandra with :

```
   kafkaStream.map(session_duration => (
        session_duration.year,
        session_duration.month,
        session_duration.day,
        session_duration.publisher_id,
        session_duration.app_id,
        session_duration.user_id
        )).saveToCassandra(configServer.getString("cassandra.keyspace"), configServer.getString("cassandra.table.daily.user_by_app"))
```

From this event, i store in 15 tables already for differents uses. number of session , number of users, duration....

I need to store in other one, but from this event i need to store 30 differents lines (date + 0 days to date + 30days).

I tried do to this :

```
    for (a <- 0 to 30) {
       val toto = a
        kafkaStream.map(x => {
            val date = new DateTime(x.date_create).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0).plusDays(toto)               
            (
                date.getYear,
                date.getMonthOfYear,
                date.getDayOfMonth,
                x.user_id
                )
        }).saveToCassandra(configServer.getString("cassandra.keyspace"), configServer.getString("cassandra.table.daily.user_30d"))
```

But it doesn t work. indeed, it saves only 12 or 15 or 20 lines or other number. Not all lines.

I have this error :

```
Could not compute split, block input-11-1480932491800 not found
```

I probably do something wrong but what? 
Could you help me please? :)

Comment: that error might indicate overload. How is your processing delay looking like?  Are you monitoring the Streaming tab of the Spark UI?

Comment: My delay is bad on the first records (3seconds )
But then it becomes good , with an average of 409ms , with an average of 232.00 records / sec isn t it? 
I have 3 servers (1 with 8 procs 32g, 1 with 8 procs  64g and 1 with 12 proc 64b)
I stopped to have the error when i use : MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2 instead of MEMORY_AND_DISK_2. 

But your answer with the flatmap decrease the delay so it s good :)

Comment: The difference is that the outer loop adds 30 extra (transform -> store) tasks while moving the loop inside, it becomes 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to represent that transformation as:

```
kafkaStream.flatMap{x => 
    (0 to 30).map{day => 
        val date = new DateTime(x.date_create).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0).plusDays(day)               
        (
            date.getYear,
            date.getMonthOfYear,
            date.getDayOfMonth,
            x.user_id
        )
    }}.saveToCassandra(configServer.getString("cassandra.keyspace"),   configServer.getString("cassandra.table.daily.user_30d"))
```